# How to use lower_bound (c++) with vector of pairs where we need to search using pair.second as our parameter?

Tags: c++

How do we use lower_bound with vector of pairs when we have to search for pair.second in the vector?

Comment: Use the overload with a custom comparitor: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: 1/ Read the linked documentation. 2/ Ask a specific question if you don't understand how to use it. But at the moment, this question is perfectly answered by "use the second overload"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you to answer your question. The question was somewhat unspecific, but you can just look at the documentation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > pairs={{2,1},{6,4},{9,6},{1,8}};
  int value=5;
  auto iter=std::lower_bound(pairs.begin(),pairs.end(), std::make_pair(-1, 5),
  [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return lhs.second<rhs.second;}
  );
  std::cout << std::distance(pairs.begin(), iter) << std::endl;
}
```